# Show Work Items in Visual Studio from a project different than your source code

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

For strange historical reasons our source code is in one TFS project (Project1), and all of our work items are in another TFS project (Project2). This means that the work items displayed in Visual Studio are totally irrelevant, out of date, or there aren't any at all because they are in Project1. We can still associate check ins with work items from Project2 by number, but is there a way to include work items from Project2 in the "Available Work Items" list, and to show queries from the other project as well?

We are using TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your Project1 queries to display work items from Project2.

Usually the first line of query is something like: `Team Project=@Project`; you can replaced it with `Team Project=Project2`

Comment: Cool I will try that.

Comment: This works, I wish I could use @CurrentIteration with this, however, since there are no iterations defined in Project1, it says that is undefined.